# how to add token for 2 different users on the same windows laptop using Windows Credential Manager?

Tags: github, token

I have 2 GitHub account and I want to add the token for both the accounts on my Windows Credential Manager.

What should I put for the "Internet or network address:" ?

[image]

The problem I'm facing is that I used "git:https://github.com" for both but with a different userid.  After creating the second userid UserB, I found that the first one UserA disappeared.

Thanks.